# Mongoose $geoWithin, find distance by miles

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, geolocation

I have a query which works correctly but i would like to make the radius based by miles instead of coordinate plain. Here is what it is like (combination between $text: search and $geoWithin: $center search.

```
let query = {
    user_type: type,
    $text: {$search: keyword},
    'loc': { "$geoWithin": { "$center": [ [longitude, latitude],  1] } }
};

Profile.find(query, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}})
```

After reading https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/center/#op._S_center
seems like the `the circle’s radius, as measured in the units used by the coordinate system.`

How would I be able to pass in a mile value and convert it to a radius system?

Comment: See also [Calculate Distance Using Spherical Geometry](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) where the very first example on the page shows conversion to miles

Comment: Thanks guys, I was using $center which was confusing me..